# Angular UI-Calendar TypeError: calendar.fullCalendar is not a function

Tags: jquery, angularjs, meteor, angular-ui, angular-meteor

I been trying to use Angular: ui-calendar with meteor, but get this error.

```
TypeError: calendar.fullCalendar is not a function
    at Scope.scope.initCalendar (calendar.js:265)
    at Object.fn (calendar.js:337)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:15896)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:16160)
    at bootstrapApply (angular.js:1679)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4523)
    at doBootstrap (angular.js:1677)
    at Object.bootstrap (angular.js:1697)
    at HTMLDocument.onReady (app.js:47)
    at fire (jquery.js:3143)
```

In meteor packages i habe:

angular 1.2.3
angularui:ui-calendar

also tried to use the package inserted directly not using meteor add.
but using the calendar.js file (which is different)

Both get the same error.

Tried this: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar/issues/267

```
       scope.initCalendar = function () {
                if (!calendar) {
                    calendar = $(elm);
                }
                calendar.fullCalendar(options);
                if (attrs.calendar) {
                    uiCalendarConfig.calendars[attrs.calendar] = calendar;
                }
         };
```

But is seems this fix doesnt work with meteor and angular-meteor.

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Comment: did you load jQuery library before angular.js?

Comment: Yes jquery is before angular.

Answer (score 2):

You should check the `initCalendar` and `destroyCalendar` methods in `angular-ui-calendar/src/calendar.js`. If they're creating the element by using:

```
angular.element(elm).html('');
```

Then you should replace it by:

```
$(elm).html('');
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that angular doesn't find jquery in window.$

if you are using es6 modules:

```js
import jquery from "jquery";

export default (window.$ = window.jQuery = jquery);
```

otherwise you should add js script in you index.html and before your app code:

```js
window.$ = window.jQuery = jquery
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may not have correctly configured the controller for your page?

I had this same issue but using ui-router, I had the controller specified incorrectly and it wasn't being wired up.  Fixing this made the calendar appear and this error go away.