# angular ui-calendar calendar.fullCalendar is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-calendar

I try to put a calendar to my project with angular ui-calendar. Scope works, I can see the message on my page but calendar does not. Here is my code:

```
    $scope.uiConfig = {
    message : "heyyyy",
    calendar:{
      height: 450,
      editable: true,
      header:{
        left: 'month basicWeek basicDay agendaWeek agendaDay',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'today prev,next'
      },
      eventClick: $scope.alertEventOnClick,
      eventDrop: $scope.alertOnDrop,
      eventResize: $scope.alertOnResize,
      eventRender: $scope.eventRender

    }
```

But I have an error like:

> calendar.fullCalendar is not a function

here is the calendar.js code that occurs that error:

```
 scope.initCalendar = function(){
      if (!calendar) {
        calendar = angular.element(elm).html('');
      }
      calendar.fullCalendar(options);
      if(attrs.calendar) {
        uiCalendarConfig.calendars[attrs.calendar] = calendar;
      }          
    };
```

I tried this solution:
 [Angular UI-Calendar TypeError: calendar.fullCalendar is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35076867/angular-ui-calendar-typeerror-calendar-fullcalendar-is-not-a-function)

But this gave an error to:

> $ is not defined

I don't know why ui-calendar is broken like this. There is no useful solution here. So pls help thanks

Comment: $ is not defined means You need to require jQuery

Comment: Thanks I added JQuery but it still same error.

Comment: Which version of angular are You using ? Angular !== AngularJS btw

Comment: my angular version is 1.7.6 and angular-ui-calendar 1.0.2.

Comment: @Msu Arven btw in calendar.js destroyCalendar function uses $(elm).html(''); and everythings ok. but initCalendar doesn't recognize $... Isn't it interesting?

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still in this trouble. I fix this problem with a specific version of fullcalendar.

```
 "fullcalendar": "~2.7.1",
```